# Minecraft [1.11.2]: Structure block won't change it block state /setblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I tried to spawn a structure block with load mode using this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:structure_block mode=load
```

and it worked. But not like I expected.
It spawned a structure block without load mode, but with data mode.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure blocks store their mode in both NBT data and as a block state, but only the NBT data will decide its mode when setting it:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ structure_block 0 replace {mode:"LOAD"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I kinda don't get it why 0 and replace? In minecraft wiki in commands, block states, structure blocks, they didn't talk about it. At least I didn't see it.

Comment: @BitCrack The syntax of `/setblock` is: `setblock <x> <y> <z> <block> [dataValue|state] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]`. I've given a `dataValue` of `0` (just because it doesn't matter in this case and it's shorter than any state) and an `oldBlockHandling` mode of `replace` (ie: it will replace old blocks).

Comment: @BitCrack However, keep in mind that numerical metadata values are not going to last as they are being replaced with blockstates (which is what you were using in your original command). Instead of a `0`, you'd use `default`.